# Print array to textarea in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to print an array to a textarea in JavaScript. My current code only prints the first element instead of all four, and I don't know why.I have tried using a regular for loop as well, but that doesn't make a difference.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var listArray = function()
        {
            var people = ["Ben", "Joel", "Mary", "Tina"]; 
            var scores = [88, 98, 100, 78]; 

            for (var key in people)
            { 
                var obj = people[key]; 
                var num = scores[key];

                var string = obj + ", " + num + "\n"; 

                document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = string; 
            }
        }

        window.onload = function()
        {
            document.getElementById("show_score").onclick = showHighScore; 
            document.getElementById("list_array").onclick = listArray; 
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="high_score" name="high_score" action="highScore.html" method="get">
            <label>Results</label>
            <br>
            <textarea cols="50" rows="4" id="box"></textarea>
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="List Array" id="list_array" onclick="listArray">
            <br>
            <input type="button" value="Show Best Score" id="show_score" onclick="showHighScore">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You just need to append, `.innerHTML = ...` will overwrite. `.innerHTML += ...` appends. Also note `showHighScore` isn't defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because of this line

```
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML = string;
```

So what you are saying, replace the content of `textbox` with the content of `string`. So at the end it just have the value of last element.

use this instead

```
document.getElementById("box").innerHTML += string;
```

So it will append the next record after previous one.

There is one more problem, on 23rd line it sasys `showHighScore` is not defined.

Comment: I was also facing the same thanks a ton! for this answer.